# Why would System.Type.GetType("Xyz") return null if typeof(Xyz) exists?

Tags: assemblies, clr, types, gettype

I have come across a strange behaviour in my (huge) .NET 4 project. At some point in the code, I am referring to a fully qualified type, say:

```
System.Type type = typeof (Foo.Bar.Xyz);
```

later on, I do this:

```
System.Type type = System.Type.GetType ("Foo.Bar.Xyz");
```

and I get back `null`. I cannot make sense of why this is happening, because my type name is correct, and I have checked with other types and they get resolved properly. Moreover, the following LINQ query finds the type:

```
var types = from assembly in System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies ()
            from assemblyType in assembly.GetTypes ()
            where assemblyType.FullName == typeName
            select assemblyType;

System.Type type = types.FirstOrDefault ();
```

Are there any reasons why `System.Type.GetType` could fail?

I have finally had to resort to this piece of code instead of `GetType`:

```
System.Type MyGetType(string typeName)
{
    System.Type type = System.Type.GetType (typeName);

    if (type == null)
    {
        var types = from assembly in System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies ()
                    from assemblyType in assembly.GetTypes ()
                    where assemblyType.FullName == typeName
                    select assemblyType;

        type = types.FirstOrDefault ();
    }

    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just give a class name (which *does* need to be fully-qualified in terms of the namespace, of course) `Type.GetType(string)` will only look in the currently executing assembly and mscorlib. If you want to get types from any other assembly, you need to specify the absolutely full name including the assembly information. As François says, [`Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) is a good way of seeing this. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string name = typeof(Form).AssemblyQualifiedName;
        Console.WriteLine(name);

        Type type = Type.GetType(name);
        Console.WriteLine(type);
    }
}
```

Output:

> System.Windows.Forms.Form, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form

Note that if you're using a strongly named assembly (like `Form` in this case) you must include *all* the assembly information - versioning, public key token etc.

If you're using a non-strongly-named assembly, it's easier - something like:

```
Foo.Bar.Baz, MyCompany.MyAssembly
```

for a type called `Baz` in namespace `Foo.Bar`, in assembly `MyCompany.MyAssembly`. Note the absence of ".dll" at the end - that's part of the filename, but not the assembly name.

You should also be aware of the differences between C# names and CLR names for things like nested classes and generics. For example, `typeof(List<>.Enumerator)` has a name of `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T] ``. The generics side is tricky to work out, but the nested type bit is easy - it's just represented with a "+" instead of the "." you'd use in C#.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Indeed, all other types I was resolving until now were either located in the same assembly or in mscorlib, so I did not catch the bug before.

Comment: Providing `System.Type.GetType` with partial assembly information works even if the assembly has a strong name. I've checked `System.Type.GetType("Foo.Bar.Baz, MyCompany.MyAssembly")` and it works even if `MyCompany.Assembly` has a strong name.

Comment: for future reference, if you want to use the backtick in a code highlight (and YOU probably will ;), use double backticks to begin and close the quote :). See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82718/237379).

Comment: @Noctis: Thanks - will attempt to remember :)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know GetType looks for "Xyz" in an assembly named Foo.Bar.dll and I'm assuming it doesn't exist.

GetType relies on your passing the exact path to Xyz in the assembly.
Assembly and namespace don't have to be related.

Try `System.Type type = System.Type.GetType(typeof(Foo.Bar.Xyz).AssemblyQualifiedName)` and see if that works.

The reason you find it with your LINQ example is that you are using `GetAssemblies` which obtains the assemblies that have been loaded into the current execution context and thus has the details it needs to find all the types within the assemblies.

Answer (score 4):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) (my emphasis):

> If typeName includes the namespace but not the assembly name, this method searches **only the calling object's assembly and Mscorlib.dll**, in that order. If typeName is fully qualified with the partial or complete assembly name, this method searches in the specified assembly. If the assembly has a strong name, a complete assembly name is required.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon a similar problem and want to leave this here

First of all your can specify the AssemblyName in the string

```
var type = System.Type.GetType("Foo.Bar.Xyz, Assembly.Name");
```

However this only works for assemblies without a strong name. The explaination is already in Simons answer `If the assembly has a strong name, a complete assembly name is required.`

My problem was I had to resolve a `System.Dictionary<?,?>` from a string at runtime. For a `Dictionary<int, string>` this might be easy but what about a `Dictionary<int, Image>`?

this would result in

```
var typeName = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32, [System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]]";
```

But I don't want to write the strong name. Especially because I don't want to include the versions since I am planning to target multiple frameworks with my code.

So here is my solution

```
    privat statice void Main()
    {
        var typeName = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32, [System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing]]";
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName, ResolveAssembly, ResolveType);
    }

    private static Assembly ResolveAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        if (assemblyName.Name.Equals(assemblyName.FullName))
            return Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(assemblyName.Name);
        return Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
    }

    private static Type ResolveType(Assembly assembly, string typeName, bool ignoreCase)
    {
        return assembly != null
            ? assembly.GetType(typeName, false, ignoreCase)
            : Type.GetType(typeName, false, ignoreCase);
    }
```

`Type.GetType(...)` has an overload which acceps a func for assembly and type resolving which in neat. `Assembly.LoadWithPartialName` is deprecated but if it's dropped in the future I could think of an replacement (iterate all assemblies in the current AppDomain and compare the partial names).