# C#.NET - Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form") returns null

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I have a snippet of code in my application (*which references System.Windows.Forms*) which attempts to resolve type information for a `Form` class like so:

```
Type tForm = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form");
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(tForm);
```

but `Activator.CreateInstance` fails because `tForm` is null.

How do I solve this?

**EDIT: Types MUST be resolvable at runtime!**

Comment: Does the project for the current assembly have a reference to System.Windows.Forms? (If you're in a multi-project solution that is)

Comment: Why not just `typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form)`?

Comment: does AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() show that System.Windows.Forms is loaded?

Comment: @Jodrell because the type information is being resolved at runtime

Comment: @activwerx, or, in this case, the type information is not being resolved at runtime. I actually meant why do this dynamically?

Comment: @Jodrell, This is a bad example, but say I have a TextBox where I can enter in the name of a type, and then that string can be used to create an instance of that type. The aim is to allow objects to be manipulated at runtime, and not as dictated by the compiled code. (hope this makes sense);

Comment: I would like to know why this has been marked down?!

Comment: @activwerx, makes sense, then the user will need to type in the Assembly Qualified Type Name, or you you'll need a type browse function that finds it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use assembly-qualified name of the type

```
Type tForm = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

Comment: Pranay Rana, I rolled back your edit, because of poor syntax highlighting

Answer (score 3):

`Type.GetType(string)` checks a few different things: if the string passed *includes assembly information*, then it will look there. Otherwise, the calling assembly and a few other system assemblies are checked (probably System and mscorlib). It **does not** check every assembly.

So, you have a few options:

- include the assembly information in the string, i.e. `"Namespace.TypeName, AssemblyName"`
- use `assembly.GetType(string)`, where `assembly` is the correct assembly
- manually loop over all the assemblies loaded in the current `AppDomain`, checking each in turn

Answer (score 2):

Check this Jon Skeet answer on this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758295/314488

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string name = typeof(Form).AssemblyQualifiedName;
        Console.WriteLine(name);

        Type type = Type.GetType(name);
        Console.WriteLine(type);
    }
}
Output:

System.Windows.Forms.Form, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

**Note that if you're using a strongly named assembly (like Form in this case) you must include all the assembly information - versioning, public key token etc.**