# Reflection of C# Types: GetType( "myType" ) vs typeof( myType ) behavior differs. Why?

Tags: c#, reflection, typeof

I would like to use reflection to get an assembly for a supplied namespace and type.  I would prefer to supply these as strings.  It is probably important to note that the namespace and type are defined in an assembly *other* than the one that is executing this code, but the executing code assembly does have a *reference* to that other assembly.

My question is why does the static GetType(string) method return null, while if I hard-code the namespace and class and use typeof() as in the if statement, I get the required result?

Here is the code:

```
   string fullClassName = "MyNameSpace.MyClass";
   Type t = Type.GetType( fullClassName  ); // this returns null!
   if ( t == null ) 
   {
      t = typeof(MyNameSpace.MyClass); // this returns a valid type!
   }
```

Thanks for any insights you may have...

Comment: Is MyNameSpace.MyClass fully resolved?

Comment: Yes, MyNameSpace is my own namespace, but is the same stuff you would put in the using statement, for example:
MyNameSpace is just my shorthand for 
MyCompany.MyLibrary or System.Windows.Forms (for example).

Comment: Is MyNameSpace contained within another namespace?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`GetType` actually queries a specific assembly (at *runtime*) for a type that might be defined within the assembly (Similar to `new Object().GetType()`). `typeof` on the other hand is determined at *compile* time.

For example:

```
// Nonsense. "Control" is not in the same assembly as "String"
Console.WriteLine(typeof(String).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Controls.Control"));

// This works though because "Control" is in the same assembly as "Window"
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Window).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Controls.Control"));
```

Comment: Thanks sirCodesAlot. The runtime vs compiletime is the key to my problem.  Perhaps I could use reflection to instantiate the class first.  I'll have a go at that and loop back if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [C#.NET - Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048171/c-net-type-gettypesystem-windows-forms-form-returns-null)

```
Type t = Type.GetType("MyObject"); //null
```

requires that you pass in a fully qualified assembly type string (see answers from link above)

```
Type t = typeof(MyObject); //Type representing MyObject
```

The compiler/runtime knows the type already becuase you've passed it in directly.

**Consideration:**

`MyObject` might exist as different things in different assemblies, therefore, why should Type.GetType() know which one your're talking about? - that is why you must pass in a fully qualified string - so then it knows exactly where to look and what to look for.

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps my example code is not clear -- I am using a fully qualified class name for the argument to GetType -- that's what "MyNameSpace" is.

Comment: Pretty sure that the addition of a namespace is not enough to fully qualify a type. For example, "System.Windows.Forms.Form" is not a fully qualified type. "System.Windows.Forms.Form, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" IS a fully qualified type. If you want to discover the fully qualified type string, do this: typeof(YourTypeHere).AssemblyQualifiedName;