# ASP.NET MVC Razor Headers and Views for Each Column Dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following Razor lines for now:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 rules="rows" frame="box">
<tr>
    <th>Türkçe Söz Dizisi</th>
    <th>English Word Sequence</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tr)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.En)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink((String)@ViewBag.Edit, "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink((String)@ViewBag.Delete, "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

However, I will add some columns automatically from the program to database table. I need a way to print this th's and td's accordingly. In short, I need a way to go through Model's dynamic columns. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** My Model type here is "Proposal". However, I want to reach dynamic attribute of Proposal.Type.Word(Tr, En, or any other added Language Enum). How can I?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    Type objectType = Type.GetType(typeof(RexamOneriSistemi.Models.Word).AssemblyQualifiedName);
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] fields = objectType.GetProperties();

<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.Name)</td>
    @foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo f in fields) {
    if (f.Name.ToString() == @HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"].ToString())
    {
        <td>
         // What to do here exactly to get item.Type.Word.[dynamic attribute]?
        </td>
    }
</tr>
}
```

I can get Razor String

```
string s = "@Html.Displayfor(modelItem => item.Type.Word." + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"] + ")"

Resulting: @Html.Displayfor(modelItem => item.Type.Word.Tr)
```

Can I insert a string to be rendered as Razor Syntax? If yes, how?

Comment: is your view strongly typed?

Comment: Yes or no, doesn't matter. I can change according to any working answer to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried this code and it works

```
 <table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 rules="rows" frame="box">
    <tr>
      @{
        Type objectType = Type.GetType(typeof(yourProjectNamespace.Models.Language).AssemblyQualifiedName);


        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] fields = objectType.GetProperties();

         foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo f in fields)
         { 

         <th> @f.Name.ToString() </th>

       }
    }

    </tr>

    @foreach (yourModelType item in Model) {
    <tr>
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo f in fields)
         { 

         <td>@Html.Display(f.Name.ToString())</td>

         }
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink((String)@ViewBag.Edit, "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink((String)@ViewBag.Delete, "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
            </table>
```

To get Assemply Qualified Name of your class , see this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758209/why-would-system-type-gettypexyz-return-null-if-typeofxyz-exists)

Comment: You rock! One more thing tough, AssemblyQualifiedName of your class? Class is "Language" for example.

Comment: Hello again, are you sure Html.Display(f.Name.ToString()) work right? Also I got some more questions on the topic, edited the question? Do you ming taking a look?

Answer (score 3):

Came across this question, wrote this maybe it will help someone else. This code will dynamically load your model into a table.

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<App.Client.Models.MyModel>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var property in Model.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties())
            {
                <th>@property.Name</th>
            }
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var modelItem in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var property in modelItem.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    <td>@property.GetValue(modelItem)</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Pretty awesome. Thank you!

Comment: And what about DisplayName() ?