# Display all fields of dto-list, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, foreach, razor-pages, data-transfer-objects

I need to display all fields of dto-list in razorpage.I have about 70 fields of each dto object.

now i have such code:

```
    @foreach (var ft in Model.DtoForeignClients)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>@ft.Name</td>
            <td>@ft.Head</td>
            <td>@ft.Customer</td>
            <td>@ft.Item</td>
            //~66 another fields
         </tr>
```

it works, but i looking for improve my code. i want to to something :

```
   @foreach (var ft in Model.DtoForeignClients)
    {
    <tr>
       @for (int i = 0; i<ft.CountOfFields;i++)
        <td>@ft[i]</td>
    </tr>
```

because i do not want to repeat  about 70 times.

How can i do this? Should i looking into IEnumerable realization for my DTO? or any another ideas, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor Headers and Views for Each Column Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920834/asp-net-mvc-razor-headers-and-views-for-each-column-dynamically)

Comment: That's a rather broad question. Every grid component does that by using reflection. Reflection is expensive though so they take care to do so in as efficient a way as possible, caching type information etc. If you *really* want an open ended grid though, a DataTable as a DTO is probably a better choice. Yet another option is to use a Javascript grid that loads data from an HTTP API endpointe, eg a Web API controller. It's easier to find *free* high-quality JavaScript grids.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i need to fo it by c# cause i have another places in my code where i need to improve such logic (business layer)

Comment: If you insist on dynamically acccessing properties, do you have any issue with the link from Mustapha Larhrouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reflection in your view to get the FieldInfo[] of the object. Replace `DtoForeignClient` with your real type of `ft`.

```
@using System.Reflection;

@{
   var fields = typeof(DtoForeignClient).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
 }

@foreach (var ft in Model.DtoForeignClients)
{
    <tr>        
      @foreach(FieldInfo f in fields)
      {
         <td>@f.GetValue(ft)</td>
      }
    <tr>
}
```